# specify submit button when testing a form view in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-tests

I'm trying to test a django form view:

**tests.py**

```
form_data = {
    'comment_text': "test comment"
}
response = self.client.post(reverse('announcements:comment', args=[self.test_announcement.id]), form_data)
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 404)  # invalid submit button
```

But my view checks to see what button was used to submit the form with:

**views.py**

```
def my_view(request, announcement_id):
  # ...

  if request.method == "POST":
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
       # ...
       if 'comment_button' in request.POST:  
           # how do I get inside this branch from a test?
           # process form
       else:
           raise Http404
```

How can I mimic the 'comment_button' being used to submit the form in my test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the `comment_button` field to `form_data`

```
form_data = {
    'comment_text': "test comment",  
    'comment_button': True
}
```